# What is the definition of the nuclear norm (aka trace norm, Ky-Fan n-norm) of a tensor?

Tags: normed-spaces, math-history, tensors, nuclear-norm

What is the direct definition for the trace norm of a tensor? 
By direct I mean without matricization.

Edit 1: By tensor, I mean a multi-way array, a generalization of vectors and matrices. (The nuclear norm of a matrix, which is a special case of a tensor, is sum of its singular values.)

In particular, I am interested on tensors $\cal T$ over $\mathbb{R}$. 
$${\cal T}\in \mathbb{R}^{d_1\times d_2 \times \dots \times d_n} $$

$\|\cal T\|_* = \|\cal T\|_{tr} = ?$

Edit 2:  Could anyone guide me where this property is defined for the first time, i.e. what is the historical origin of the definition?

Comment: The trace is just the sum of the eigenvalues, and you don't need a matrix representation to define eigenvalues.

Comment: Eigenvalues are not even defined for a general "non-square" matrix. Did you mean singular values?

Comment: By tensor do you mean an array with more than two indices?

Comment: If a tensor (by which I mean a rank 2 element of the tensor algebra of the vector space $V$) has a matrix representation, then it is a square matrix. Linear operators and bilinear forms are examples, and corresponding to both types of rank 2 tensor are eigenvalues whose number (up to multiplicity) is equal to the dimension of the vector space $V$.

Comment: Yes, by tensor I mean a multi-way array. What are the other meanings for a tensor?

Comment: @ William, from your explanation it looks like we are talking about different mathematical objects. It is weird that two different  things with different properties have the same name. What I know as tensor is a generalization of matrix and could be rectangular too.

Comment: The nuclear norm of a matrix is defined as the sum of its singular values (I believe Horn and Johnson *Matrix Analysis* has it). It would be natural to define the nuclear norm of a tensor as the sum of its singular values. I am not an expert of SVD for tensors, but I know it is not in general unique. However, I am not sure whether the non-uniqueness regards the singular values or the singular vectors. If it's the latter, then the definition of nuclear norm can be extended safely to tensors.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me that there ought to be a reasonable notion of the nuclear norm of a tensor.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Well the fact is there is. A big field in machine learning are doing trace norm regularization for completing tensors or tensor recovery  when a number of elements are known. The point is I do not get to a good source of direct definition.